# URL routing in ASP page

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, global-asax

The Actual Address is

```
www.Domain/nav/Default.aspx
www.Domain/nav/Fruit/Apple.aspx
```

All I want is to hide the 'nav' and 'aspx' text from address.

```
www.Domain/Default
www.Domain/Fruit/Apple
```

I tried some Code in Global.asax file

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("PageRoute", "{0}", "~/{0}.aspx");
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("PageRoute", "{0}", "~/nav{0}/{0}.aspx");
```

But its no way working, Can anyone please help me out with the correct code order

Comment: I guess you are mixing ASPX and ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Are you using MVC.Net? If not which web framework are you using?