# Add value to {0}

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-routing, global-asax

I start out with these addresses

- www.example.com/nav/Default.aspx
- www.example.com/nav/Fruit/Apple.aspx

What I want is to hide the `nav` and `aspx` text from the address.

- www.example.com/Default
- www.example.com/Fruit/Apple

I tried some code in Global.asax file

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("PageRoute", "{0}", "~/nav/{0}.aspx");
```

And this works now:

```
www.example.com/Default
```

But now I want to append the `Page`, like this:

- www.example.com/DefaultPage

  RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("PageRoute", "{0}Page", "~/nav/{0}.aspx");

Why is this code not working? What is the correct way to do so?

Comment: Please share more context.

Comment: "`"{0}"+"page"`" is just "`"{0}page"`" (not "`"{0} page"`" as one answer says), but I don't think that's what you want at all. Can you describe the effect you're hoping to get?

Comment: okay, let me edit my Question

Comment: @Faizan that edit didn't make your question more clear.

Comment: @Faizan What you want is when someone goes to `example.com/hellopage` they get to see the `"~/nav/hello/index.aspx"` page, is that correct?

Comment: @Stijn Vsit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826642/url-routing-in-asp-page

Comment: Question is now updated

Comment: @Mateusz Question is now updated, see to it

Comment: @Stijn Question is now updated

Answer (score 4):

The expression `"{0}" + "page"` is equivalent to just a single string `"{0}page"`, so you don’t need to manually concat two strings, but you can just write it as a single one.

```
route.MapPageRoute("Christianty", "{0}page", "~/nav/{0}/index.aspx");
```

Comment: @poke I stand corrected, my initial tests didn't work for some reason, testing again makes it work. +1

Comment: @Stijn Are you serious? Hah, that’s quite lucky then—I was about to delete the answer because I have no idea about ASP routing xD